# Selecting an updating the same record in one query

Tags: sql

There are identical questions here, but I don't understand how I would be able to apply the suggested solutions to my problem, so here goes...

I have the following code where I want to change the StudentID from 7 to 8

```
UPDATE Student
SET StudentID = 8, Forename = "Adam", Surname = "Sai", YearID = 1,
WHERE StudentID = 7
```

This is in the context of a Tkinter treeview where I want to be able to update any value which is selected.
[Tkinter Treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMVTD.png)

I get the following error:

```
Execution finished with errors.
```

Result: near "WHERE": syntax error
At line 1:
UPDATE Student

```
                SET StudentID = 7, Forename = "Adam", Surname = "Sai", YearID = 1,
                WHERE
```

I am wondering whether this is because I am trying to update and identify the record both using StudentID.

Comment: An error "near" usually means "just before" - where you have a rogue comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error in your query is the comma before the where clause. Eliminate it and try again.